# The app hanging if you try to close a connection

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webrtc

I'm using Swift 3 with a WebRTC pod called "PodRTC".

If I open a connection, close and open another works perfect. But if I have an open connection for some unfortunate reason I try to created new par connection, the app blockeding. Or the opposite, if you try to close a connection that is not open the app also hangs.

These hanging happen randomly, but always when I call a "close" method. Here is an example:

```
private func prepareNewPeer() {
        if let peer = self.peer, peer.responds(to: #selector(RTCPeerConnection.close)) {
            do {
                peer.close()
            }
        }
        self.chatChannel = nil
        self.peer = nil
        ....
```

The application simply hangs, but neither does it generate errors. Apparently, it does not loop because processing is low. It looks like some bug inside the library.

This happens in the .close () method call. I tried to protect the method in every way, but to no avail.

OBS: It is worth mentioning that sometimes it is not just the app that hangs but the entire operating system. I can not play anything else until I compile a new version with Xcode or reboot the phone or wait a few minutes.

---

**To interrupt the app using Xcode's "Pause program execution" button and see what's happening on the various threads:**

The line in my code that stopped, was ".close()" and previous comment.

[image]

Comment: 1) Hanging and crashing are very different things.  2) To debug a hang, try to interrupt the app using Xcode's "Pause program execution" button and see what's happening on the various threads.  3) Are you doing these network operations on the main thread?

Comment: @PhillipMills Sorry about my English. I put a print of what I see when I stop the application. I believe it is running on the main thread

Comment: I don't know how webrtc works but I would try dispatching all network operations to a background thread and see if it fixed the hang problem.

Comment: @PhillipMills Continues, is now available on "Thread 1". This happens after switching peerConnection many times (about 5 or 6 times). The idea that I clean peerConnection and create another, is there no alternative?

Comment: @LuísDeMarchi Have you found solution for this?

Comment: The same problem occurs sometimes with WebRTC v. 90 (downloaded and compiled from the source). I don't have a solution, but as the hack you can wrap the close() call into background `DispatchQueue`, then your app won't hang (only the background thread will hang)

Comment: Found my own comment from the last year. The problem still exists. My previous workaround didn't work and just mask the problem. The peer.close() method not just hands itself but hands some other thread too (which is clear indication of deadlock).